# Rails: each in random order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my code:

```
    <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>


      <li><%= answer.content %></li>


    <% end %>
```

I want to order the answer objects randomly. What would be the most efficient way to do so considering the amount of possible answers is less than say 10?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [`shuffle`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) method like this:

```
question.answers.shuffle.each do |answer|
```

Comment: is shuffle an addition from rails or is it ruby?

Comment: It's Ruby. I linked to the API.

Comment: What about the opposite case, where you intend to sort by an ascending value?

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland, you can use [`order`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) for that. In this example `question.answers.order(:field_name)`.

Answer (score 3):

How about this

```
<% question.answers.shuffle.each do |answer| %>


      <li><%= answer.content %></li>


    <% end %>
```